# How do we use Corda provided VaultQuery API to run a subquery with EXISTS clause?

Tags: corda

I have state with following configuration

```
data class NodeState(
    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier(),
    val name: CordaX500Name,
    val active: Boolean,
    val services: List<Service>):LinearState, QueryableState
```

and my Persistent schema is following

```
class PersistentNodeState(
        @Column(name = "linearId")
        var linearId: String,

        @Column(name = "name")
        var name: String,

        @Column(name = "active")
        var active: Boolean,

        @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @CollectionTable(name = "node_services",
                joinColumns = arrayOf(
                        JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"),
                        JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id")
                )
        )
        @Column(name = "service")
        var services: Set<String>
```

Now I would like to query state using VaultQuery similar to following SQL query. How should I do it?

```
SELECT * FROM NODE_STATE as A where EXISTS (select * from NODE_SERVICES as B where B.TRANSACTION_ID = A.TRANSACTION_ID AND B.SERVICE = 'LEAD_COUNSEL')
```

How do we use Corda provided VaultQuery API to run a subquery with EXISTS clause??

Comment: Would you be able to restate that SQL query in plain English, for those of us less familiar with SQL?

Comment: I have state object A containing set/list of B objects. Through vault query service I would like to query any States A which contains given value within list of B

Comment: Would it be answered by this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930564/querying-nested-collections-in-linearstate-states

Comment: JDBC connectivity and running plain OLD SQL query is not available through the CordaRPCClient. Check interface CordaRPCOps

Comment: Yeah - but the node is just backed by a regular database. You would connect to that via JDBC as you normally would for a database. Is that feasible?

Comment: For short term may be but when we separate REST layer from Corda Layer, the recommended approach is to use CordaRPCClient for CRUD operations. I would highly recommend to add more features available in the CordaRPCClient/CordaRPCOps and in the vault services.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the current `VaultQuery` API, documented here: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html. You would have to connect to the node's database directly and issue an SQL query.

You can do this from within a flow as follows:

```
// Connecting to the node's database.
val session = serviceHub.jdbcSession()

// Writing to the node's database.
val preparedStatementWrite = session.prepareStatement("update my_table set value = ? where key = ?")
preparedStatementWrite.setInt(0, 100)
preparedStatementWrite.setString(1, "my_key")
preparedStatementWrite.executeUpdate()

// Reading from the node's database.
val preparedStatementRead = session.prepareStatement("select value from my_table where key = ?")
preparedStatementRead.setString(0, "my_key")
preparedStatementRead.executeQuery()
```

You can also do it from outside the node using standard Java.